# How do I transfer a Google App Engine application billing to a different Google Checkout (Wallet) account?

Tags: google-app-engine

My company has an application hosted on Google App Engine for which I had enabled billing back when we couldn't setup a Google Checkout account with a Google Apps for your Domain account.

So what I did is add the company's credit card to my personal Google Checkout account, and use my personal Checkout account to pay for the GAE app weekly fees.

Now that Google Checkout (aka Google Wallet) can be setup with domain accounts, I would like to transfer my company's GAE app billing to the Wallet/Checkout account that I have created with my company's Google App domain account.

However, I don't see any obvious way to do this in the *Billing settings* section of my app's administration console, and the documentation only mentions how to transfer billing responsabilities to someone else.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to log in with the account that you want to be the billing administrator and then go to the `Billing Settings` from the `Admin Console` and click on `Take Over Billing`. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Take over billing on google app engine]

Comment: This is a good answer, but unfortunately I can't do it. The problem is that I am already the billing administrator for the app, and I don't have another account that could take it over. So `my_company_account@mydomain.com` is the current billing admin, but it's using the `my_personal_account@gmail.com` Checkout account. I want to keep `my_company_account@mydomain.com` as the billing admin, but switch to the `my_company_account@mydomain.com` Checkout account. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Add any email you like as viewers in the permission and the login with that account..! The billing administrator has to be at least a viewer of the project, and has to login and take over.. you cannot transfer it..

Comment: But wouldn't that require me to setup a Google Wallet account for that new email account? I can do it, but it looks like a lot of hoops to go through to "simply" switch to a different Google Wallet account...

Comment: The idea is to loging/assign the account that has already the google wallet thing to the google app engine app, and then take over.. which account has to enable what is up to you...!

Comment: @PascalBourque The Google Wallet account that you want to charge.. belongs to an e-mail address.. right?! The one that someone has access to.. Add that e-mail to the permissions of your GAE application and then login with that e-mail and take over! Just be careful when you're receiving the invitation to join not to be logged in the previous account in the background, cause you might endup accepting another e-mail.. check mail/accept invite from another session/incognito/browser if on the same machine

Comment: Yes, the Wallet account does belong to an email address. My point is that the email address it belongs to is already set to be the "billing administrator" of the app...

Comment: @PascalBourque aha.. then I guess. disabling it and enabling it again.. or contact the support for that, they are very helpful and fast on replies..